# JPQL/HQL: Sorting entities by similarity to a specimen?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql, similarity, hibernate-search

I want to query for entities which are similar to a given entity (of the same type).
The similarity is (in the simplest case) defined as number of the same items in a member collection.

How would the JPQL/HQL query look like?

What I tried:

```
       SELECT wuSimilar, COUNT(*) AS score FROM WorkUnit wuBase 
           LEFT JOIN wuBase.tags AS wubTags
           LEFT JOIN WorkUnit wuSimilar ON wubTags IN wuSimilar.tags
           WHERE wuBase = :base
           GROUP BY wuSimilar
           ORDER BY score DESC
```

This is basically searching, so I could use Hibernate Search, but not sure if it's not an overkill. Alternatively, I am open to things like ElasticSearch, in which case the question would be, does it pay of to bring it in just for this one case? I won't probably have another search in this project.

Answer (score 0):

I was quite close, I just relied too much on my SQL knowledge.
JPQL only uses `JOIN` for declared entity relations.

When selecting a list defined by expression in `WHERE`, it has to be comma join.

```
       SELECT wuSimilar, COUNT(*) AS score FROM WorkUnit wuBase 
           LEFT JOIN wuBase.tags AS wubTags
           , WorkUnit wuSimilar
           WHERE wuBase = :base AND wubTags IN (wuSimilar.tags)
           GROUP BY wuSimilar
           ORDER BY score DESC
```

Seems to work, going to test.

Comment: I would have used Hibernate Search, it's designed for this and a lot more efficient than the super join solution. Not least, you get auto-tagging capabilities and natural language processing for a better control of the similarity functions.